# How to Change the indentation in a boxed list environment

Tags: lists, environments, indentation, tcolorbox

I have a list environment inside a tcolorbox, and I would like to get some control on the indentation, as sometimes I use multicols inside and it gives weird results because of the large indent of the items.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newtcolorbox{objbox}[1] {colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1, before skip=0.5cm, after skip=0.5cm}  %   

\newenvironment{objectives}{%                                                                                                           
    \begin{objbox}{Objectives:} \begin{list}{\(\bullet\)}{}%                                                                    
}{%                                                                                                                         
    \end{list} \end{objbox}%                                                                                
}%  

\begin{document}

\begin{objectives}
    \item foo:
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \item one
        \item two
    \end{multicols}
\end{objectives}

\end{document}
```

If possible I'd like it to have an optional parameter to control the distance, with a set default value when empty, but I'd be happy with a single command that changes it for the whole document.

Comment: You can easily control indentation in lists by using the `enumitem` package, but the large space between your items is caused by them being spread over two columns that span the page width.  Can you clarify what you need.

Comment: Do you really mean the (horizontal) indent of all items or only the (horizontal) distance between `one` and `two` or do you mean the vertical distance between `foo` and `two`?

Comment: My bad. Yes, I mean the horizontal indent of all items. Even if I only have one column, I find that the horizontal space is somewhat redundant since the box itself already draws attention to the items.
I had already experimented with the column separation using the properties of `multicols`, but I had not understood how to modify the list parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three solutions: one uses the parameters of `enumitem` (mainly the `wide` option) and `multicols`, the second is based on the `tasks`package and the last uses the `shortlst` package, which is available on CTAN, but not a package of TeX Live, nor MiKTeX (for licensing reasons. If an item overflows into the next column, this is done automatically by shortlst, but it doesn't manage items which require several lines. For this case, I had to define a `\paritem`, which defines a `\parbox` command with an optional argument, the number of columns it will spread over, and a mandatory argument, its contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{shortlst, setspace}
\newenvironment{boxeditemize}[1][3]{\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\mbox{\textbullet}}%
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/#1-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\begin{shortitemize}}%{1.333}
{\end{shortitemize}}%
%%
\newtcolorbox{objbox}[1] {colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1, before skip=0.5cm, after skip=0.5cm} %

\newenvironment{myobjectives}{%
    \begin{objbox}{Objectives: (with \texttt{enumitem})} \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin =*]%
}{%
    \end{itemize} \end{objbox}%
}%

\newenvironment{otherobjectives}[1][3]{%
 \begin{objbox}{Objectives (with \texttt{shortlst})}%
\begin{boxeditemize}[#1]
}{%
 \end{boxeditemize} \end{objbox}%
}%

\newcommand\paritem[2][1]{\item \parbox[t]{#1\shortitemwidth}{#2\medskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myobjectives}
 \item foo:
  \begin{multicols}{2}
 \item one
 \item two
 \end{multicols}
\end{myobjectives}

\par
\begin{objbox}{Objectives: (with \texttt{tasks})}\settasks{style = itemize, item-indent = 0em, label-offset =-0.2em, before-skip = -1.5ex, after-skip =-3ex}%
\begin{tasks}(2)
 \task* foo:
 \task one
 \task two
 \end{tasks}
\end{objbox}

\begin{otherobjectives}[2]\setstretch{2.5}
 \item foo:
 \item one
 \item two
\end{otherobjectives}

\begin{otherobjectives}[2]
 \item foo;
 \paritem[2] {Bla bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla bla. }
 \paritem{Bli bli bli bli bli. Bli bli bli bli bli. Bli bli bli bli bli. Bli bli bli bli bli. Bli bli bli bli bli. }
 \item one
 \item two
\end{otherobjectives}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do mean the horizontal space between `one` and `two` you might try putting the multicol inside a parbox with a set width, for example like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newtcolorbox{objbox}[1] {colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1, before skip=0.5cm, after skip=0.5cm}  %   

\newenvironment{objectives}{%                                                                                                           
    \begin{objbox}{Objectives:} \begin{list}{\(\bullet\)}{}%                                                                    
}{%                                                                                                                         
    \end{list} \end{objbox}%                                                                                
}%  

\begin{document}

\begin{objectives}
    \item foo: % empty line below this is important

    \parbox{5cm}{
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{multicols}
    }
\end{objectives}

\end{document}
```